# Bad shell script interpreter? Works sometimes

Tags: bash, shell, script

I have a weird situation where some of my shell scripts that use `#!/bin/sh` as the shebang sometimes work - other times they yield the following message:

> bash: ./newshit.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Is there something simple that I'm missing?

Comment: have you check your sh file if there is really a ^M behind the shebang?

Comment: there definitely isn't

Comment: but why the bash state there is a ^M? try using another editor to view the script file.

Comment: Did you made this file in windows and ftp to unix?

Comment: njd's answer explains quite nicely ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That ^M is a dead giveaway - it looks like the script has Mac line-endings (Ctrl-M) instead of Unix line-endings (Ctrl-J).

It won't appear as a literal ^M - in fact depending on your text editor it might not be shown at all.

You don't say which operating system you have, so I'm not sure which tools you have on your system but could you try to get a character (not hex) dump with:

```
od -tc newshit.sh
```

...and tell us whether the /bin/sh is followed by \r, \n or \r\n ?

I'm expecting you'll see something like:

```
0000000   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   s   h  \r
```

Or if you run:

```
cat -e newshit.sh
```

...that will display the carriage return character if it's there.

Comment: it looks like `\r  \n`. I wrote this code in notepad++ on windows, and executed it in ssh on linux.

Comment: That's probably the problem, I would have never guessed! Anyhow, any tips to fix this?
 +1 good answer :)

Comment: ` cat -e newshit.sh
#!/bin/sh^M$
`

Comment: Just copy the content from the windows, and in the session of linux, create a new file using vim and paste the content in it.

Comment: In Notepad++, Edit > EOL Conversion > UNIX Format; or use 'dos2unix' on the Linux end.

Answer (score 2):

`dos2unix newshit.sh` will fix it.

Edit: Alternatively, if for some reason you aren't able to find dos2unix, this simple script will do it:

```
tr -d '\r' < newshit.sh > newshit-fixed.sh
```

Comment: unknown command. I can't find the package via apt-get either

Comment: It would help if you tell what Operating System you are using.

Comment: Debian Lenny. .

Comment: `apt-get install tofrodos`

Comment: Recent Ubuntu/Debian distros don't have it; you'll need to run: `apt-get install tofrodos` first, and use `fromdos` instead.